# React router v4 prevent matching child routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, switch-statement, router

I encountered a problem with React Router v4 Switch component. I'm quite surprised that i couldn't find a relevant thread for this problem. A common Switch will look like this:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/path1' component={Path1Component}/>
  <Route path='/path2' component={Path2Component}/>
  <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
  <Route component={NotFound}/>
</Switch>
```

This means that when i'm on a path: '/' i get a Home component, on '/path1' i get a Path1Component and on path '/foobar' i get a NotFound component. And that is perfectly fine

However when i'm on '/path1/foobar' route i also get the Path1Component. This behaviour is not correct in every case - this time i do not want any nested routes for '/path1' route. '/path1/foobar' should get a NotFound component, any string, with '/' or without after '/path1' should return NotFound component.

What would be the preferred resolution to this problem? I could just add exact to every path, but wouldn't that be overbloating the code? I feel like that should be the default, but it's not the case.

Even on React Router v4 docs, like [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match). I see this problem - here '/will-match/foo' will also match. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4958), but to make it short : *it would break existing code*. If this were to change, you'd have to do `exact={false}` if you want to match child routes without doing 'path1/child1'.